# app.use express serve multiple html

Tags: node.js, html, express, web

I am using node.js and express for my site. I need to be able to direct the user when he clicks a link in index.html. 
I have three pages: index.html, presentation.html, join.html all in the public folder.
This is how I did the routing in server.js:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(express.bodyParser({ keepExtensions: true, uploadDir: __dirname + '/_tmp'}));
```

And this is how I wrote the links in index.html:

```
<a class="btn" href="/presentation">Presentation</a>
<a class="btn" href="/join">Join</a>
```

when I run the server I get index.html but when I click one of the links to navigate to the other pages I get this error:

```
Cannot GET /presentation
```

When I try to add to server.js this:

```
app.get('/presentation',function(req,res){
  res.render('public/presentation.html' , { root : __dirname});
});
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here is my App layout:

```
App
/pulic
      indx.html
      join.html
      presentatio.html
server.js
```

How can enable navigation?

Answer (score 2):

I used mine and it worked

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const router = express.Router();
const path = require('path');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

var publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');




router.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "/"));
});


app.get('/new_deposit', function (req, res) {
    res.sendfile(publicPath + '/new_deposit.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As it is configured, you can access the HTML files directly as files `href="/join.html"`.

If you want to use routes for the static files, try this:

```
var publicPath = path.join(__dirname, 'public');

app.get('/test', function (req, res) {
  res.sendfile(publicPath + '/test.html');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the routes:
I was using either res.render or res.sendFile
when I used res.sendfile it worked fine.